# printing elements of a list in racket

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

My question is how can i print the elements of a list two times, the code i have tried is given below

```
(define duplicate-list
(lambda (mylist n)
(cond ((null? mylist) '()) 
      ((< n 2) (cons (car mylist)
                     (duplicate-list mylist (+ n 1))))
      (else 
       (duplicate-list (cdr mylist) 0)))))

(define duplicate 
(lambda (mylist)
(duplicate-list mylist 0)))
```

The problem in this code is that, it works fine only when i give it a list as input, this fails to work when i give it an input of a nested list.

```
>(duplicate '(a 1 b 2 c 3 r x)) ->  a a 1 1 b b 2 2 c c 3 3 r r x x
>(duplicate '( (a 1) b ((c)) 2)) ->((a 1) (a 1) b b ((c)) ((c)) 2 2)
```

Whereas, the expected outcome needed should be

```
(duplicate '( (a 1) b ((c)) 2 z 3) = ( (a a 1 1) b b ((c c)) 2 2 z z 3 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong approach to build the output list, you have to recur over the `car` and `cdr` parts, given that this is a list of lists. Try this:

```
(define (duplicate lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         '())
        ((not (pair? (car lst)))
         (cons (car lst)
               (cons (car lst) ; here we duplicate each element
                     (duplicate (cdr lst)))))
        (else
         (cons (duplicate (car lst))
               (duplicate (cdr lst))))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(duplicate '((a 1) b ((c)) 2 z 3))
=> '((a a 1 1) b b ((c c)) 2 2 z z 3 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using pattern matching via [`match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) -

```
(define (duplicate l)
  (match l
    ((list (list a ...) b ...)      ; nested list
     (cons (duplicate a)
           (duplicate b)))
    ((list a b ...)                 ; flat list
     (cons a
           (cons a
                 (duplicate b))))
    (_                              ; otherwise
     null)))
```

It works as expected -

```
(duplicate '((a 1) b ((c)) 2 z 3))
; '((a a 1 1) b b ((c c)) 2 2 z z 3 3)

(duplicate '())
; '()
```